# Masstranist - Access properties from middleware

Tags: masstransit

I use Masstransit in multi-tenant application. On Web Api part I use Owin middleware to resolve tenant ID from DNS. I can access it globaly from services using OWIN environment.
I've created a Masstransit middleware to intecept the message and get tenant ID. In some cases I need to access it. 
Since the bus is singleton-scoped, how can I access it?
I tried with IConsumeObserver.PreConsume, in debug I see private properties from the consumer, but I can't access them.

UPDATE:
Each message has TenantId property. We use Entity Framework global filter to filter all queries by TenantId. It is set on Unit of Work that we inject into consumer:

```
public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<IMyCommand>
{
    private readonly ITenantConfiguration _tenantConfiguration;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public MyConsumer(ITenantConfiguration tenantConfiguration, IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _tenantConfiguration = tenantConfiguration;
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMyCommand> context)
    {


        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Unit of work is instantiated before I get TenantId from the message. I use Ninject and if I set unit of work to .InTransientScope() it solves my problems.
If I use Web Api, I get tenantId from Owin Middleware startup class:

```
var domain = context.Request.Host.Value.ToLower();
context.Set<object>("tenantId", tenantId);
```

Later, I can access it from services:

```
var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext();
var owinEnvVars = owinContext.Environment;
var currentTenantInfo = owinEnvVars["tenantId"]
```

Is it possible to have something like that when Masstransit messages?

Comment: Some code would help

Comment: Yeah, a little code would help get you moving forward. Otherwise, I'm not sure I'm connecting to your problem.